# LibGDX Android Emulator Problems

Tags: libgdx, android-emulator

Okay, so I dont know if its my program or if eclipse is just bad at running an android emulator. My application runs fine as a runnable jar file however trying to run it in an android emulator I get a FATAL ERROR:MAIN and it fails to load my package classe. I've also tried using Andy OS as an emulator but it doesnt work on that either. Also I tried running a libgdx set up with nothing on it and i get the same errors.

```
08-03 18:44:16.455: E/Trace(6706): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-03 18:44:16.508: W/dalvikvm(6706): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/caleb/gspikes/AndroidLauncher; (14)
08-03 18:44:16.508: W/dalvikvm(6706): Link of class 'Lcom/caleb/gspikes/AndroidLauncher;' failed
08-03 18:44:16.508: W/dalvikvm(6706): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa615a908)
08-03 18:44:16.511: E/AndroidRuntime(6706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 18:44:16.511: E/AndroidRuntime(6706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.caleb.gspikes/com.caleb.gspikes.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.caleb.gspikes.AndroidLauncher" on path: /data/app/com.caleb.gspikes-1.apk
```

This is some of the logcat message when using Andy OS

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me but when i configured the build path in the order and export I selected the external jars I used.